# How can I rewrite URL using mod_write in htaccess file for opencart

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart

It should be  [from like this](http://www.website.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=957_958&product_id=17623)  to result as [shown here](http://www.website.com/Product/Samsung/Note-Tablet)

I'm new to this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to System » Server » Use SEO URL’s
2. Rename your .htaccess.txt file to .htaccess by removing the .txt file extension
3. Change .htaccess content:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /opencart/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]`

[Source](http://www.sitefixit.com/scripts/opencart/how-to-solve-seo-urls-not-working-in-opencart.php)